# Woocommerce custom stock update after successful order

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom database table linked to my Woocommerce tables with some information like SKU and Stock. I want to add custom function to update this table after successful order (when Woocommerce updates product stock). I've tried to do something with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'wpet_testnote' );
function wpet_testnote() {

// Lets grab the order
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->add_order_note( 'Stock Updated.' );
```

I've tried to testing my action with basic order note adding, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: "it's not working" -> elaborate..

Comment: Thanks for answer @Kashyap. As I was mentioned my question before, I'm trying to run a function after succesifull order (for example, getting stock after order), I've tried to do this with 
add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'wpet_testnote' );
add_action( 'reduce_order_stock', 'wpet_testnote' );
but these are not working for me.
So, my real question is how can I execute a function after order placed in woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to submit the `$order_id`. this one works on my end:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'wpet_testnote' );
function wpet_testnote( $order_id ) {
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order->add_order_note( 'Stock Updated.' );
}
```